# The embedded key is not showing in the forms

Tags: java, spring, spring-data, spring-data-jpa, spring-roo

I'm using Spring Roo 2.0.0.RC1.

I have a table that has a composite key of two strings. So I defined the PersonId entity :

```
@RooToString
@Embeddable
@RooSerializable
@RooIdentifier(dbManaged = true)
public class PersonId {

    private String postalCode;

    @NotNull
    private String city;
}
```

Then I created a Person entity with PersonId as an identifier type :

```
@RooJavaBean
@RooToString
@RooJpaEntity
@RooEquals(isJpaEntity = true)
public class Person {

    @EmbeddedId
    private PersonId id;

    @Version
    private Integer version;

    private String address;
    @NotNull
    private String currentPosition;
}
```

The project compiles fine, but the problem is that the PersonId's fields don't show on the CRUD form.

How can I make the embedded composite key show in the CRUD form ?